# Convert Number with Format into a String

Tags: sas

How do you convert a number or currency variable into a character string that keeps the format as part of the string?

For instance, the below code has a character variable, `MSRP_to_text`, and currency variable, `MSRP`. When I set `MSRP_to_text` equal to `MSRP`, it takes the unformatted number and converts it to a string, so the dollar sign and the comma are gone.

```
DATA want;
   SET SASHELP.CARS(KEEP=MSRP);
   ATTRIB MSRP_to_text FORMAT=$8.;

   MSRP_to_text = MSRP;
RUN;
```

In other words, the code is currently converting `$36,945 -> "36945"`, but what I really want is `$36,945 -> "$36,945"`.

Is there a way to keep the dollar sign and comma in the string?

Comment: Why did you attach $8. format to the new variable? If you want to set its length to $8 then use the LENGTH attribute. There is no need to attach the $8. format since SAS already knows how to display character strings.

Comment: Do you want the value left aligned or right aligned in the new character variable? `'$36,945 '` vs `' $36,945'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VVALUE` function will retrieve the formatted value of a variable.

```
MSRP_as_text = VVALUE(MSRP);
```

`VVALUEX` goes one step further for the case of the variable name being dynamic; such as being stored in a different variable, or is computed from some name patterning algorithm.

```
name = 'MSRP';
formatted_value = VVALUEX(name);
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I figured SAS had to have something that does it, but after searching a while I wasn't seeming to hit the right combination of keywords. I like that you added more info about `VVALUEX`. I would have never thought to look for a function like that, but it could be really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ATTRIB statement, Use the PUT function to convert number to Character. and it will keep the text value with format. Since the original Format of MSRP is DOLLAR8. , so using same format in put statement will suffice the purpose

```
DATA want;
   SET SASHELP.CARS(KEEP=MSRP);
   MSRP_to_text = put(MSRP, DOLLAR8.);
RUN;

proc contents data=want; run;
```

Comment: Although this answer works, I choose Richard's since `VVALUE` doesn't require a format like `PUT` does.

Comment: `VVALUE` uses the format associated with the variable during data step run-time.  If you want to map the value using a specific or dynamic format, disregarding the current or no format, the `PUT/PUTN/PUTC` functions let you do that.